# Laravel multi-page anchor language switcher

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization

I would like to start with the fact that I'm new to Laravel framework.

I've a fully working website(HTML, CSS, JS) and I'm given the task to add a feature - **anchor language switcher** (between Bulgarian(BG - default locale) and English(EN)).

```
<a href="/">BG </a><a href="/en">EN </a>
```

Upon switching the language, it should redirect to the same page, but in the chosen language.
Also the URLs should look like this:

```
example.com/
example.com/en
example.com/en/about
```

I've done my best to find a working solution online, but to no avail. What I know I must do is set my routes in **web.php** `Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });`
but that only affects a part of my task - removing the '.html'.
I changed the

`'locale' => 'bg',  'fallback_locale' => 'en', 'alt_langs' => array ('en'), 'locale_prefix' => '',`

and added a few translations to **resources/lang/en/lang.php**

```
    'welcome' => 'Welcome',
    'title'=> 'English title',
    'message'=> "English message"
```

A step-by-step explanation would be very much appreciated, as I'm still incompetent, but eager to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can read this https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#configuring-the-locale):

```
Route::get('/{locale?}', function ($locale = config('app.locale')) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('welcome');
});
```